# Echo command and new line with tr command not working

Tags: shell, tr

I am running a command to replace `,` in a file to newline

```
echo `tr ',' '\n' < file.txt` > file.txt
```

This command is converting

```
a,b,c
```

to

```
a b c
```

rather than converting it to

```
a
b
c
```

Can anyone explain to me why it is happening and work around for this?

Comment: If you are looking to replace "," with a newline, the charset order in `tr` is wrong. ',' should be first param and '\n' the second one.

Answer (score 3):

First off, running a command with both input and output redirected to the same file is dangerous. It might happen to work, as you've seen, but it can clobber the contents of the file as you're trying to read it, depending on the order in which things happen.

To avoid that issue, let's simplify the commands:

```
$ cat file.txt
a,b,c
$ tr , '\n' < file.txt 
a
b
c
```

So the `tr` command itself is working as you expect. Now let's try echoing the output:

```
$ echo `tr , '\n' < file.txt`
a b c
```

The shell executes the command and uses its output as the arguments to `echo` -- but the output is split into words delimited by whitespace (including newlines).

You can avoid this, if you're using sh, bash, or a similar shell, by quoting the argument:

```
$ echo "`tr , '\n' < file.txt`"
a
b
c
```

If you shell supports it (most do), you can use `$(...)` rather than backticks:

```
$ echo "$(tr , '\n' < file.txt)"
a
b
c
```

I find it a bit easier to read, since you can easily distinguish between the beginning and the end of the construct; it can also be nested.

Finally, at least for what you're doing, there's no point in using `echo`.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
tr , '\n' < file.txt > $$ && mv $$ file.txt
```

This tranlates the contents of `file.txt`, writing the output to a temporary file (`$$` is the process id of the current shell, handy for generating temporary file names). It then renames the temporary file to `file.txt` -- but only if the first command succeeded. that avoids clobbering your input file if something goes wrong.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please explain why; perhaps I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for.

```
tr ',' '\n' < file.txt > tempFile.txt  
mv tempFile.txt file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this

```
sed -i 's , \n g' file.txt
```

Comment: Using a space as a delimiter is a bit unusual. Nothing wrong with it, I suppose, but `s/,/\n/g'` is more common.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt | tr "," "\n"
```

which can then be redirected to your file (via intermediate tmp file as mentioned by [Keith in his comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14676753/2361131))